# How do I loop through files in folder to create a parameter list to pass into another script in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a Windows batch file that processes a bunch of files. As part of this I use the following line:

```
forfiles /p "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /m "%SupportLog%*" /c "cmd /c logreader.py @file > \"%~dpn1%ParsedLogDir%\@file_Logreader.txt\"
```

This works OK, but essentially loops through all my files (`%SupportLog%*`) and passes each one by one into the *logreader.py* script.

What I really want to do is to create a list or parameter of all these files and pass all of them at once into the Python script, such the command that should be run would resemble:

```
logreader.py "logfile.log" "logfile.log.1" "logfile.log.3" .....
```

I tried to use the `set` command within the `forfiles` command like that:

```
forfiles /p "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /m "%SupportLog%*" /c "cmd /c set PARAMS=%PARAMS%@file "
```

However, when run this and leave the `ECHO ON`, I see:

```
forfiles /p "C:\Path\log" /m "logfile.log*" /c "cmd /c set PARAMS=@file "
```

This is incorrect. And when I do `echo %PARAMS%`, I get no result.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: In your first line of code, there is the closing `"` missing (however this does not solve your problem of course)...

Comment: many thanks aschipfl, oddly though I have been using this line as is with no issue for a while. I do, however see what you mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks all. I eventually used a combination of the pointers listed above (and elsewhere) to come up with the following (an excerpt of the full batch file):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set SupportLog=support.log
Set LogDir=\var\log
set PARAMS=

for %%A in ("%~dpn1%LogDir%\%SupportLog%*") do (
    set PARAMS=!PARAMS! "%%A"
)

logreader.py %PARAMS% > "%~dpn1%ParsedLogDir%\%SupportLog%_Logreader.txt"
```

So, the a shortcut to the batch file is created in the "SendTo" folder, I can then right click the zipped log file and "SendTo" the batch, and all works as expected.

Perhaps I should switch to PowerShell for things like this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

forfiles is complicated or may even be buggy. It does not support the quotes within `/c "cmd /c ...."` must be replaced by hex characters `0x22`, or by `\"`.

```vb
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /A-D "logfile.log.?"') do (
    set _logfile=!_logfile! "%%a"
)
echo logreader.py %_logfile%
```

output:

```
logreader.py  "logfile.log.1" "logfile.log.2" "logfile.log.3" "logfile.log.4" "logfile.log.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

`forfiles` creates a new `cmd` instance per each loop iteration, so a variable `PARAMS` only exists as long as the containing instance.

If you want to use `forfiles` and work around that issue, you might do the following:

```
rem collect all items in a temporary file as a single line:
del /F /Q "loglist.tmp" 2> nul
forfiles /P "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /M "%SupportLog%*" /C "cmd /C echo | set /P _=\"@file \" >> \"loglist.tmp\""
rem pass over the content of temporary file as parameters:
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%L in ("loglist.tmp") do logreader.py %%L
rem clean up temporary file:
del /F /Q "loglist.tmp" 2> nul
```

---

Relying on a variable for collecting the parameters rather than a temporary file, the following could work:

```
rem collect all items in a variable:
set "PARAMS="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%L in (
    'forfiles /P "%~dpn1%LogDir%" /M "%SupportLog%*" /C "cmd /C echo.@file"'
) do set "PARAMS=!PARAMS!%%L "
endlocal & set "PARAMS=%PARAMS%"
rem pass over the content of variable as parameters:
if defined PARAMS logreader.py %PARAMS%
```